# Auto mount volumes

Tags: docker, rhel, podman

I wonder if it is possible to make Docker automatically mount volumes during build or run container phase. With podman it is easy, using `/usr/share/containers/mounts.conf`, but I need to use Docker CE.

If it is not, may I somehow use host RHEL subscription during Docker build phase? I need to use RHEL UBI image and I have to use companys Satellite

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but would a bash script that automatically mounts volumes help? Most programming languages can run bash scripts through a command called system(), so if docker can run system calls, a bash script would probably work.

Comment: With podman, I can specify which volumes should be mounted automatically, even during build phase:
```cat /usr/share/containers/mounts.conf
/usr/share/rhel/secrets:/run/secrets
```. I'm looking for similar thing in docker

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know what podman even is.

Answer (score 0):

A container image build in docker is designed to be self contained and portable. It shouldn't matter whether you run the build on your host or a CI server in the cloud. To do that, they rely on the build context and args to the build command, rather than other settings on the host, where possible.

buildah seems to have taken a different approach with their tooling, allowing you to use components from the host in your build, giving you more flexibility, but also fragility.

That's a long way of saying the "feature" doesn't exist in docker, and if it gets created, I doubt it would look like what you're describing. Instead, with buildkit, they allow you to inject secrets from the build command line, which are mounted into the steps where they are required. An example of this is available in the [buildkit docs](https://github.com/moby/buildkit/blob/master/frontend/dockerfile/docs/syntax.md#run---mounttypesecret):

```
# syntax = docker/dockerfile:1.3
FROM python:3
RUN pip install awscli
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=aws,target=/root/.aws/credentials aws s3 cp s3://... ...
```

And to build that Dockerfile, you would pass the secret as a CLI arg:

```sh
$ docker build --secret id=aws,src=$HOME/.aws/credentials .
```